# how can i use singleton beans to transfer data from one user to another user?

Tags: javascript, java, html

when I use `Html.geolocation` I get the `geolocation` of my current position. I want o transfer this data to another user

1. I have created a DB and created a login and logout sessions
2. I want to send the live location data from one user to another user
3. I will map them on a map

can I use singleton beans? what can I use to transfer between two users or two sessions?